# Graph API: Get all versions of all OneDrive items in single query

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-files

Is there any way in which I can get all the versions of all OneDrive items in my Drive using Graph API. And I want a single query to complete this work.

DriveItemVersion resource type doesn't seem to support this (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/driveitemversion?view=graph-rest-1.0). It looks like we need a separate query to get versions of each OneDrive item. This is not a very efficient way.

Let me know if there is any workaround/fix for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible and would be extremely inefficient. Just as an example, I have ~100k DriveItems in my OneDrive. Attempting to retrieve all of the items, and each version would take an exceedingly long time.

It is far more efficient to retrieve the minimum `DriveItem` properties you need using a [Delta query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-delta?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http). You can then process individual `DriveItems` in batches. Once complete you can then retrieve another Delta and processes any files that have changed in the meantime.

I would also suggest taking another look at your requirements. There are very few scenarios where it makes sense to query *every* file in a Drive. You shouldn't attempt to apply the same patterns used for local/networked storage to cloud storage solutions (be it OneDrive, Google Drive, DropBox, etc.). They are much more akin to a database of binaries than a file system.

Comment: Thanks. Though it will be a time and bandwidth-consuming operation there are few use cases where it's unavoidable. E.g. I want to download all the items in my OneDrive (along with their versions to save multiple queries). Or another scenario would be I want to download only changed versions using delta query. But it looks like both these operations are not really possible using existing Graph APIs.